# prove binomial multiplication less than 1

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

please show me how to prove the following.

Given $m >= n,n\geq2$ prove

$\binom mn$ $\cdot \frac{1}{n^m} < 1$

**------UPDATE--------**

Given the inequalities:

$(\frac{m}{n})^n \le \binom mn \le \frac{m^n}{n!} \le (\frac{em}{n})^n$

Will that make things easier? This is the direction I take, but I still don't see any direct result by applying this inequality.

Comment: Please show us what work you've done already.

Comment: @m.a. please assume n>=2 then

Comment: Hint: the binomial coefficient appears in the expansion of $(x+y)^{m}$. Maybe you can do something clever with that!

Comment: @JamesHolbert Please see my update for the direction I take

Comment: @m.a. I still don't see this. Can you give more hints?

Comment: If you expand $(x+y)^{m}$ you get an expression that is the sum of several binomial coefficients with some weights (depending on x and y). If you choose x and y carefully, then you can use that to get an upper bound on $\binom mn$.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write $m=n+a$ (so $a\geq 0$) and try to prove it by induction (on $a$).

For the induction step it may be useful that
$$
\binom{p}{q}+\binom{p+1}{q}=\binom{p+1}{q+1}
$$

from Pascal's triangle.

Also $p!<p^p$

Comment: yeah but that requires $a$ to be  discrete while it is continuous

Comment: so $m,n\notin\mathbb{Z}$?